# Migration Failure from SO: Questions Won't Close

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535903/how-do-i-quit-telnet-in-iterm now has 6 close votes, and has been down voted.

When I added the sixth close vote the popup said just "close".

Something seems to be stuck.

*Additional*: Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539283/windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-fails-to-install-with-error-0x800f0818

And this time I remembered to capture the popup:

[image]

Comment: Migrations failed again...

Comment: You remembered to capture it, but you forgot to draw a freehand circle.

Comment: @BoltClock: I could claim the use of unicorn hair brush to create a perfect one dimensional line; I could also claim my coffee was still brewing; but in reality: mea culpa.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, bug related to auto-removing comments that contain the destinations site URL (new feature) -- now fixed. Sorry about that.

Nulls. Can't live with 'em, can't ⚅

Comment: That last line is the best thing I've read **all year.**